# What is the ~ operator used for on a scss file?

Tags: sass

I do not understand the meaning of the `~` char in the following line of code in a scss file:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's in the file path, I guess it's the "Bootstrap user home directory".

On Linux or Unix, home directories are named `~`:

- `~` : the current user directory (yours)
- `~juan` would be your home directory.
- `~bootstrap` : bootstrap's user directory (ex: `/home/bootstrap` or maybe `/usr/share/bootstrap` or `/opt/bootstrap`)

More examples on https://askubuntu.com/questions/656869/how-does-using-the-tilde-work-as-a-shortcut-to-my-home-directory

So maybe your bootstrap files are located in a particular directory owned by a `bootstrap` user having that directory as his `$HOME` directory.

In that case, it's not at all related to Sass, it's only a regular file path.

Answer (score 0):

That is not part of sass, it's actually a feature of `sass-loader` which you are probably using with webpack.

What it does is importing the file relative to the node_modules folder instead of the current file.

Check out `sass-loader`'s documentation for more details: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports.